# How to call a remote bat file using jinterop

Tags: batch-file, dcom, j-interop

GlassFish Application Server uses a script, asadmin.bat, that in turns starts a JVM.

I'd like to call this script using jinterop and DCOM  from Java on a remote machine.  I can't find any help on this specific usage.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Björn -- You are my new hero!  It all worked perfectly.  Thanks so much.  I don't have enough points to give you points yet - regrettably...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the Windows Scripting Host Shell to execute some program or batch on a remote computer.

The code looks like:

```
// Create a session
JISession session = JISession.createSession(<domain>, <user>, <password>);
session.useSessionSecurity(true);

// Execute command
JIComServer comStub = new JIComServer(JIProgId.valueOf("WScript.Shell"),<IP>, session);
IJIComObject unknown = comStub.createInstance();
final IJIDispatch shell =     (IJIDispatch)JIObjectFactory.narrowObject((IJIComObject)unknown.queryInterface(IJIDispatch.I ID));
JIVariant results[] = shell.callMethodA("Exec", new Object[]{new JIString("%comspec% /c asadmin.bat" )});
```

If you need the output from the batch you can use StdOut to read it.

```
JIVariant stdOutJIVariant = wbemObjectSet_dispatch.get("StdOut"); 
IJIDispatch stdOut =  (IJIDispatch)JIObjectFactory.narrowObject(stdOutJIVariant.getObjectAsComObject());

// Read all from stdOut
while(!((JIVariant)stdOut.get("AtEndOfStream")).getObjectAsBoolean()){ 
    System.out.println(stdOut.callMethodA("ReadAll").getObjectAsString().getString()); 
}
```

Comment: It worked great after I solved multiple layers of Firewalls.
But where does this variable come from:
wbemObjectSet_dispatch

Comment: ok i forget the line 'final IJIDispatch wbemObjectSet_dispatch = (IJIDispatch)JIObjectFactory.narrowObject((results[0]).getObjectAsComObject());' so it came from the results array.

Comment: I'm getting an error while running this, do I have to enable "Use Surrogate Process" flag?